# How can I implement the has_and_belongs_to_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to implement `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between two models and a join table. How is it possible? What would be routes declaration and model files declaration?

Take a example: a country can have many companies and companies can be in many countries.Can i achieve this association by doing so?

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :countries
end

class Country < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :countries do
       resources :companies 
    end

    resources :companies do
      resources :countries 
    end
end

class CreateCountries < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :countries do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateJoinTableCountryCompany < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_join_table :countries, :companies do |t|
       t.index [:country_id, :company_id]   
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It should work? Did you try it? Do you have any errors?

Comment: yes i tried it but it is just implementing one to many. not many ot many

Comment: How did you check it? In console you should be able to see `Company.first.countries` and `Country.first.companies`